# Open window based on user input

Tags: android, if-statement, numbers

I have a text box (number) and a button below it.

so I want to know what code I need to write for this behavior:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="62dp"
        android:layout_y="247dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

**if user enter number 1 or 11 or 21 or 31 .......(in box)
and hit button then open window 1 (or page)

if user enter number 2 or 12 or 22 or 32 or 42 .....(in box)
and hit button then open window 2..............**
```

similar next for 10 windows

i'm new in java. so plz explain in detail 
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any java code for it yet?

Comment: no i don't have any code for it.

Comment: You probably should make an attempt. This is a very easy thing to do so you should at least be able to get started. If you can't get started then you need to read [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) and [Android](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while clicking the button, you can get the entered text in textbox, convert it in to integer, and from it's first digit, you can write the code for popupwindow.

Some sample Code

```
Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
String value = text.getText().toString();
int number = Integer.parseInt(value);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          checkConditionForNumber is a function
                checkConditionForNumber(number);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, in your activity

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            if(text.equals("1") ||
                    text.equals("11") ||
                    text.equals("21") ||
                    text.equals("31") ) {
                //take action
            }
```

Add more else if depending upon your requirement